Create cutom router for redirecting to homepage || Magento 2
In Magento 2, I want to set custom route, like after baseurl/custom-route/any url it should be redirected to homepage or base url. Here, I had tried to create type of RouterList and extend RouterInterface. As shown below, but it is not working as required.
Please provide solution for this.
I had tried below solution. By creating below di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="bv_custom" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>

and below is defined controller class  Route.php
<?php
namespace Vendor\module\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

/**
 * Class Router
 */
class Router implements RouterInterface
{
    private $actionFactory;
    private $response;
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * Router constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        ResponseInterface $response,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function match(RequestInterface $request): ?ActionInterface
    {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        if (strpos($identifier, 'shop') !== false) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->actionFactory->create(Redirect::class);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        return null;
    }
}


Do you face any issues, then added description into question.

You can handle redirection directly from the backoffice.
Marketing > Seo > Url Rewrites
No code needed there
